# Is it possible that the number of dead tuples is less than the number of rows updated/deleted in PostgreSQL table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am performing a stress test on our product in which there would be update/deletion of large number of rows from partitioned tables and indexes in multiple databases. I verify the counts and then perform `vacuum` operation.

I observed that the number of dead tuples is equal to the number of rows updated/deleted in most of the cases, which is expected. 
Both `pg_stat_get_dead_tuples()` and `pgstattuple()` functions returned same number of dead tuples. As I know the former function returns estimated counts and the later exact counts.

But in one case the the number of dead tuples is found to be less than that of the updated rows. 
Number of tuples updated in the table was 5000000.
`pg_stat_get_dead_tuples()` returned 5000000 as dead tuple count.
But `pgstattuple()` returned only 4999552 count.

What could be the reason for this behavior? Is this expected?

Thank you.

Comment: How about number of hot updates? Any chance it's equal to 448?

Comment: All the 5000000 tuples were updated in a single transaction. I think HOT updates can not reuse the dead tuple space from the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer lies in HOT + Defragmentation.

Quoting from [here](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD)

> Heap Only Tuples (HOT): The feature eliminates redundant index entries
>   and allows the re-use of space taken by DELETEd or obsoleted UPDATEd
>   tuples
>   **without performing a table-wide vacuum**.  It does this by allowing single-page vacuuming, also called "defragmentation".

Also,

> Defragmentation: ... **moves the surviving tuples** to coalesce all the
>   free space into one "hole".

Comment: Thanks for answering. But, can HOT updates reuse the dead tuple space from the same transaction? I think no.